# Why and how are quaternions 'bilinear'?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quaternions, cross-product

What does it mean when we say that quaternion composition is 'bilinear'? I have observed that some authors write quaternion multiplication as:

[image: form 1]

While others specify:

[image: form 2]

Excuse the poor images, StackExchange did not seem to like my LaTeX.

Note that the sign on the vector cross product has been altered. I think this is a result of the bilinear property of quaternions, but I am not sure.

If this is the case, which is the 'true' quaternion multiplication? Is it simply a matter of convention? What alterations to the properties of quaternions take place if I choose one over the other?

My understanding was that quaternions offered a 'unique' representation of rotations in R3. Is this not impacted by the existence of two multiplication operators?

My background is Applied Math/Engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bilinear**:  Bilinear over the reals.  Linear in each variable separately.  (1) Linear in the first variable:
$$
(tp)q = t(pq),\qquad
(p_1+p_2)q = (p_1q)+(p_2q)
$$
for all quaternions $p, p_1, p_2, q$ and all reals $t$.  (2) Linear in the second variable (left to the reader).

....

*which is the 'true' quaternion multiplication?*

Well, Hamilton said $ij=k$, so I guess that is your second one.